# jqgrid - any event before a page unloads

Tags: jqgrid

Does jqGrid have any event before a current page unloads? 
I have virtual paging turned on and when you are between 2 pages e.g page 1 and page 2, I want to trigger something when page 2 loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `loadComplete` event to capture when page 2 loads, which seems like it should be good enough.